# Stripe-angular dependency injection error Unknown provider:

Tags: angularjs, node.js, dependency-injection, stripe-payments

I'm injecting stripe angular into a module to create stripe tokens, but i seem to be having some dependecy injection issues:

i've got both the Stripe.js and the angular-stripe directive loading in index.html

```
<!-- Stripe includes-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/stripe-angular/stripe-angular.js"></script>

<!-- Ends Stripe includes -->

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/form.js"></script>
<script src="factory/appointments.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="directives/datepicker.js"></script>
 --><script src="controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/form-controller.js"></script>
```

and I'm injecting correctly based on the docs:

```
angular.module('formApp')
.controller('formController', ['$scope', 'Appointment', 'stripe' , function($scope, Appointment) {
Stripe.setPublishableKey('my-key-here');
}]);
```

what am i doing wrong?

here is my error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: stripeProvider <- stripe <- formController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=stripeProvider%20%3C-<div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">tripe%20%3C-%formController
```

Answer (score 0):

You list `stripe` as a dependency, but never pass it into your function:

```
.controller('formController', ['$scope', 'Appointment', 'stripe' , function($scope, Appointment) {
```

Just add a `stripe` parameter:

```
.controller('formController', ['$scope', 'Appointment', 'stripe' , function($scope, Appointment, stripe) {
```

Answer (score 0):

By `angular-stripe directive`, do you mean https://github.com/gtramontina/stripe-angular ?

If so, you are misunderstanding its usage(yes its doc is poor). You should add `stripe` as a module dependency instead of a service to inject. Change the code in your `app.js` to something like this:

```
angular.module('formApp', ['stripe']);
```

And remove the `stripe` in your injection annotaion, then you are good to go.

You may also need to add `Stripe.setPublishableKey('your-publishable-key');` into a suitable place, possibly a `run` block or a `config` block.

Comment: i'm actually injecting one module into another module - I have my formApp module being injected into the myApp module like this: angular.module('MyApp', ['ngCookies','ngResource', 'ngMessages', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'formApp', 'stripe' ])

Comment: having added stripe as above, I'm trying to check it using - var key = Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_7LnUmjmnIwkkWJUvgKlqLtSd');
  console.log(key); in formApp but getting undefined - is that correct?

Comment: @Mobaz I don't know if `Stripe.setPublishableKey()` will return a value... But the only reason you were getting the Error is you tried to inject `stripe`.

Comment: @Mobaz I would recommend you to call `Stripe.setPublishableKey()` in the `run` block of your root module, or find a better angular Stripe library that will take care of this in the config phase for you.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are just fine.

First make sure that you are loading the required files:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script src="/vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/angular-stripe/release/angular-stripe.js"></script>
```

Then add the `angular-stripe` module to your app:

```
angular.module('app', [ 'angular-stripe']...
```

In your config block load the `stripeProvider` and initialize it with your Stripe API key.

```
angular.module('app').config(function(stripeProvider) {

  stripeProvider.setPublishableKey('yourapikey');

  ....
```

Finally you can use this in your controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('CheckoutCtrl', function(stripe) {

    stripe.card.createToken(card) ...
```

Ensure you do all these steps. My guess from your error message is that you did not load the `angular-stripe' module in your app which would then cause any call to`stripeProvider` to fail with that error.